# Is it possible to generate arbitrary functions in QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I was trying to write a QuickCheck test for the identity

```
f $ y = f y
```

My initial plan was to write an arbitrary generator that returns functions & Integer, having the signature `Gen (Int -> Int, Int)`

and in the `prop_DollerDoesNothing` test that function application with / without the `$` gives the same result.

This was my code:

```
  prop_DollarDoesNothing :: Property
  prop_DollarDoesNothing =
    forAll arbitraryFuncInt (\(f, y) -> (f $ y) == (f y))

  arbitraryFuncInt :: Gen (Int -> Int, Int)
  arbitraryFuncInt = do
    f <- elements [(\x -> x*2), (\x -> x+3), (\x -> x-2)]
    y <- arbitrary :: Gen Int
    return (f, y)
```

And it generated the following helpful error message:

```
    * No instance for (Show (Int -> Int))
        arising from a use of `forAll'
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    * In the expression:
        forAll arbitraryFuncInt (\ (f, y) -> (f $ y) == (f y))
      In an equation for `prop_DollarDoesNothing':
          prop_DollarDoesNothing
            = forAll arbitraryFuncInt (\ (f, y) -> (f $ y) == (f y))
```

So, I fixed the error and got the test working by applying the arbitrary function and returning a pair of ints from `arbitraryFuncInt`

```
  prop_DollarDoesNothing :: Property
  prop_DollarDoesNothing =
    forAll arbitraryFuncInt (\(x, y) -> x == y)

  arbitraryFuncInt :: Gen (Int, Int)
  arbitraryFuncInt = do
    f <- elements [(\x -> x*2), (\x -> x+3), (\x -> x-2)]
    y <- arbitrary :: Gen Int
    return (f $ y, f y)
```

My questions are:

1. is it simply not possible to return arbitrary functions that aren't fully applied due to not having an instance for `Show`?
2. Can I write an instance for `Show (Int -> Int)` to make `# 1` possible?
3. Can QuickCheck generate arbitrary functions given a type signature, for cases where I'm testing identities that are true for all functions (of a given type). Above, I specify the 3 test functions by hand, I'd like to automate that somehow, ideally something like this `f <- arbitrary :: Gen (Int -> Int)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

QuickCheck has support to generate, shrink and show functions, using the `Fun` type. `CoArbitrary` enables generation of functions. It is then converted to a (possibly infinite) trie-like structure, that can be inspected and shrunk to a finite value (because a test failure only depends on finitely many inputs), which can then be shown as a counterexample.

Concretely, you can write properties as function that take a `Fun` argument, which is a wrapper around `(->)` using the mechanism I described. Deconstruct it with the `Fn` pattern to get a function.

```
prop_dollarDoesNothing :: Property
prop_dollarDoesNothing = property $ \(Fn (f :: Int -> Int)) x ->
  (f $ x) === f x
```

For more information

- The QuickCheck implementation: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html
- The paper "Shrinking and showing functions" by Koen Claessen, which appears to be paywalled, but his talk is online: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CH8UQJiv9Q4

Answer (score 1):

`Arbitrary` can generate functions just fine (provided the arguments are instances of [`CoArbitrary`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html#t:CoArbitrary)), it's just the showing part that doesn't work. There's not really a good way to show a function.

This is a common problem, and therefore QuickCheck provides the [`Blind`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.11.3/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Modifiers.html#t:Blind) modifier. It basically fakes a `Show` instances for any type, not actually showing any information about the value. Of course this somewhat diminishes the debugging-usefulness of a failing test case, but there's not much that can done about this.

Comment: Smallcheck does boldly include an orphan `instance (Serial Identity a, Show a, Show b) => Show (a -> b)`.