# Why is this implementation a bad instance of the Foldable Typeclass?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, quickcheck, foldable, typeclass-laws

I'm working through the wonderful [Haskell Book](https://haskellbook.com/). At the end of the Traversable chapter (21), I need to write an instance for the following Tree:

```hs
data Tree a =
    Empty
  | Leaf a
  | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

Here is [a link to the full code](https://github.com/javinor/haskell-book/blob/main/ch21/Ch21_12_ExercisesTree.hs) of my solution. The exercises recommends trying to implement both `foldMap` and `foldr`. This is how I implemented `foldr` (without putting much thought into the invocation order):

```hs
foldr _ z Empty = z
foldr f z (Leaf x) = f x z
foldr f z (Node left x right) = 
  f x $ foldr f (foldr f z left) right
```

I then implemented `foldMap` as follows:

```hs
foldMap f Empty = mempty
foldMap f (Leaf x) = f x
foldMap f (Node left x right) = 
  foldMap f left <> f x <> foldMap f right
```

When I run QuickCheck's `foldable` test batch, I get some failures. Changing my `foldr` implementation to the following makes all the tests pass:

```hs
foldr _ z Empty = z
foldr f z (Leaf x) = f x z
foldr f z (Node left x right) = 
  foldr f (f x (foldr f z right)) left
```

I tried running the failing test case on my own, but couldn't recreate the failure:

```sh
*Ch21_12_ExercisesTree Data.Monoid> tree = Node (Node (Leaf (-5)) 3 (Node (Leaf 3) 5 Empty)) (-2) Empty
*Ch21_12_ExercisesTree Data.Monoid> foldr (<>) (mempty :: Sum Int) t
Sum {getSum = 4}
*Ch21_12_ExercisesTree Data.Monoid> foldMap Sum t
Sum {getSum = 4}
```

I suspect there's something I'm not figuring out about the `fold`ing function that QuickCheck is using.

Questions:

1. Why are failures occurring?
2. Is there a way to get the function used in the test by QuickCheck?

Answer (score 4):

`foldr` can be obtained from `foldMap` [by using the `Endo` monoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23319967/2751851), with the `a -> b -> b` function turning `a` values into `b -> b` functions that can be (monoidally) composed. That being so, if your `foldMap` is...

```
foldMap f Empty = mempty
foldMap f (Leaf x) = f x
foldMap f (Node left x right) = 
  foldMap f left <> f x <> foldMap f right
```

... the corresponding `foldr` must be:

```
foldr f z Empty = id z  -- mempty amounts to id
foldr f z (Leaf x) = (f x) z
foldr f z (Node left x right) = 
  ((\e -> foldr f e left) . f x . (\e -> foldr f e right)) z  -- (<>) amounts to (.)
```

If we tidy that up a little...

```
foldr f z Empty = z
foldr f z (Leaf x) = f x z
foldr f z (Node left x right) = 
  foldr f (f x (foldr f z right)) left)
```

... we get the correct definition of `foldr` as written in your question. As the difference between the implementations has to do with the order of composition, trying out a non-commutative monoid readily leads to a failing case, [as you have found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65533224/2751851).

On the QuickCheck subquestion, I defer to [DDub's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65534334/2751851).

Answer (score 3):

As you already deduced, the reason you're getting failures is because the two implementations are distinguishable, which you can observe by using a non-commutative monoid.

---

Getting the function used by quickcheck is a not so simple.  See, for example, [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50630036/14802384) about `Show`ing functions generated by quickcheck for a little more info.

The way to get `Show`able functions out of QuickCheck is to wrap the function in [the `Fun` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Function.html).  That said, the code you're calling ([found here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.5.6/docs/src/Test.QuickCheck.Classes.html#foldable)) just uses functions directly, so they can never be shown.  One option you could try is to create your own version of the `foldable` function where you use the type `Fun a b` in place of `a -> b` and `applyFun` as necessary to apply the functions.

Answer (score 2):

I just realized that I used a commutative Monoid ... I was able to recreate the failure using a non-commutative Monoid:

```sh
> ftree = fmap (First . Just) tree
> foldr (<>) mempty ft
First {getFirst = Just (-2)}
> foldMap (First . Just) ft
First {getFirst = Just (First {getFirst = Just (-5)})}
```

This is probably a simple case. I'd imagine that in production code with real data types this could be much more complicated.